# Solutions to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to group some solution for a given differential equation based on their type (as a homework), and I have a problem with it. The available types are general, particular, singular. What does the singular mean exactly? Can we call, for example, the $\pm\sqrt{x+1}$ a general solution because of the $\pm$ sign? Is the $y=c e^x$ a general solution to the $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{dx^2}=y$ equation, or just the $y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$? Can the constant be a complex number in the Cauchy-problem?

I think the answer to the last question is yes, but we were only doing it with real numbers in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution of this equation is given by $$y(x)=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}$$

Comment: I know, I can solve it. I was asking if the $y(x)=ce^x$ is called a general solution or not.

Comment: it is not a general solution, combine the solution like above

Comment: But how would you call that solution? Particular?

Comment: no i think it is not a particular solution, it is one solution of two solutions and by a linear combination  we get all solutions

Comment: Thanks; so it does not have a special name. Could you please answer the other questions too?

Comment: the constants are in the general case real numbers

Comment: Can't they be complex numbers? And what does the singular solution mean?

Comment: To answer that question you should first define "Function" and "Differential Equation".  E.g. for $y'=0$, you should ask yourself, what kind of solutions do you want to get. Is $\tilde{y}=a+ib$ a solution? If so, what is $\tilde{y}'$?Check your definitions and include them in your question.